# htaccess redirect with up to three variables

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Please help me to redirect 
`http://subdomain.example.com/page/subpage`

to
 `http://www.example.com/index.php?subdomain=subdomain&page=page&subpage=subpage`

with htaccess. I'll learn how it is done with a final code. Some variables may be omitted at some pages.